# How to get post id and insert to inpout field in WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, forms, custom-post-type

I am developing a property website right now and each of the property ( custom post ) will have a form within. The form will be asking for customers basic info, but aside from that I would like to add a property Id field in it, so that I will know from what property does the request came from.

I would like to populate the property ID field with the post ID from wordpress. Of course the property ID field is just a 'Read Only' field.

I am using Gravity Form plugin to generate a form.

My Current Form fields are: Name, Email, Phone, and Property Id (which I would like to be populated with the wordpress post ID value).

Is there anyone who can help me achieve this.

Your help will be much appreciated. I am also open for any better solution.

Comment: `<?php the_ID(); ?>` echoes the current page ID. Add it to the `value` attribute of your input. Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID

Comment: @rnevius but in my case I am using a plugin to generate a form, how am I able to populate the id field I made with the post id from wp? sorry if I did not mention this before.

Comment: You're making a plugin, or you're using a plugin?

Comment: @rnevius I am using a plugin.

Comment: ...What plugin? You're not giving us all the details we need. Please update your question with all relevant details.

Comment: @rnevius apologies, I've just updated my question above.

Comment: You're going to need to make a [custom field that is populated dynamically](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Allow_field_to_be_populated_dynamically) via [filters in your *functions.php* file](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_field_value_$parameter_name).

Answer (score -1):

In your WordPress loop, when you get data from the database, you can use [the_ID()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID) function.

For example, when you do your loop and when you want to build your form you can use something like this:

```
<input type="text" readonly value="<?php the_ID();?>" name="your field name">
```

Comment: Try to explain please, why?

Comment: `the_ID()` outputs the ID so you need to remove echo.